# Go - multiple by scientific notation

Tags: go

I'm looking for an example of how to calculate `1 * 10 ^ x` in golang.

For example `1 * 10 ^ 18` gives me the output of `24` instead of `1000000000000000000`

essentially I'd like to be able to perform `x * 1e{y}`

Answer (score 2):

In GoLang `^` is used for bitwise XOR.

You can learn about GoLang operators from here. [GoLang Operators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/go-operators/)

You can perform the above operation using the `math` in GoLang.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    x := 1.0
    res := x * math.Pow(10, 18)
    fmt.Printf("%f", res)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think other answers have already pointed this out, but `^` is bitwise XOR. When you do `1 * 10 ^ 18`, you're essentially evaluating `10 ^ 18`. Since, 10 evaluates to `01010` in binary and 18 evaluates to `10010` in binary, `10 ^ 18` would result in `11000` or 24.

To get the result you want, you should do:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    multiplier := 1.0
    exponent := 18
    result := multiplier * math.Pow10(exponent)
    fmt.Printf("%f * 10 ^ %d = %f", multiplier, exponent, result)
}
```

In this example, the work is being done by the `Pow10` function in the math package. It produces a value equal to ten to the power of the value given to the function. Then we multiply this by the multiplier to get the result. Running this code would yield the following:

```
1.000000 * 10 ^ 18 = 1000000000000000000.000000
```